# Get X and Y of a click on an ImageIcon, Java

Tags: java, image, graphics, java-2d, mouselistener

I'm looking to add interactivity to an image but cannot see a way off adding a mouselistener to it. I would like to get the X & Y of where whas clicked on the image.

The Flow if the image is:

```
tileset = new ImageIcon("xx.png"); //ImageIcon Image that wants to be clicked
label.setIcon(tileset); // assigned to a label
panel.add(label);       //assigned to a panel
tileScrollPane = new JScrollPane(panel); // Assigned to a scrollable pane
frame.add(tileScrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER); // then onto a JFrame
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to add a MouseListener to the label:

```
label.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent event) {
        // Handle click - coordinates in event.
    }
});
```